# Server not accepting client request in java through sockets

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

Server "Waiting for clients" and client sending a request to the server, but the server is not accepting the client request.
EchoServer.java

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class EchoServer
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        {
            System.out.println("Waiting for clients...");
            ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(9898);
            Socket soc=ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection established sucessfully");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

EchoClient.java

```
import java.net.Socket;

public class EchoClient
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try 
        {
            System.out.println("Connection started");
            Socket soc=new Socket("localhost",9898);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't understand what could be the issue and thanks in advance

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html
Which constructor are you expecting to use?
In any case JVM may discard your attempted Socket instantiation as it does not actually do anything

Comment: Is it a full code? because if it is, your client code does not have any sense. Logically your client socket destroyed immediately after it was created and whole client ends. So... there is no need to make a physical connection to the server at all. Not sure but maybe optimized byte code just removed that never used object and never creates it. You have to write something to socket, try to read from  it or at least do something with your socket object...

Comment: It works for me. What version of Java are you using?

Comment: It could be a matter of timing. what happens first - socket destroyed/JVM ended or connection opened on OS level/server got it and after that socket destroyed/JVM ended...

Comment: @Vadim javac wouldn't optimize out `new Socket`, whether it was referenced by a variable or not. It's composed of logic, and such optimizations would result in undesirable, potentially buggy, results. Maybe if it were an unused primitive, javac may remove it. JIT would definitely not optimize out all the logic within the constructor of `Socet` for the same reasons (may use EA to unwrap the object, although unlikely due to the size of `Socket`). Is it not working for you? If so, what version of Java are you using?

Comment: yes, as i said i'm not sure about optimizer and actually do not care about it, but... after Socket object created what JVM will do in this code? right after method ends that Socket object becomes unreferenced, marks to be garbaged by GC and more as long as it is a main method - JVM exits. so...?

Comment: @Vadim The constructor *doesn't* end until a connection has been established, or throws an `IOException`. It's not a matter of timing, it has nothing to do with the VM. So everything you've been saying lacks any basis - the lack of a variable referencing the socket in the OPs code has *nothing* to do with it.

Comment: So, how version of Java you asked about, can be related to the problem?

Comment: I'm using java 1.8

Comment: Which update version of 8? Is it 8u144? @Vadim Bugs... Did you even run his code? It works fine. If it's not working for him, and he's using a different version of Java, there could be a bug. If not, then he's doing something wrong.

Comment: That was initial question - is it actual code or not? ...bug in jdk around socket... h-m-m... Anyway if client cannot establish connection there must be an exception... is it there?